# Enviar notificações PHP

Tags: php, html5

Vejo muitos sites utilizando o pushcrew (ou outros serviços) para enviar notificações, mesmo que o navegador esteja fechado.

Minha dúvida seria, é possível fazer isso diretamente usando a API Notification do HTML 5?

Como faria pra via PHP enviar notificações e eles receberem mesmo com a tela fechada?

Por onde devo iniciar minhas pesquisas?

Answer (score 3):

Para implementar este recurso utilize a Push API do Html5. Fique atento com a compatibilidade com os browsers.

Outro cuidado que deve ter é que o PHP não é uma linguagem boa para implementar daemons, isto é, implementar websockets é um tiro no pé. O PHP foi feito para que os processos iniciem e tenham um fim, manter um processo sempre ativo vai aumentar muito o uso de memória e processamento de seu servidor. Como o PHP não possui maneiras de gerenciar memória terá que contar apenas com o garbage collector, o que é uma péssima ideia. (Caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre isso, aqui uma explicação https://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die)

Apesar da Push API não utilizar websockets, tenha isso em mente, é melhor usar outra linguagem se deseja um sistema de notificações em tempo real. E tambem pense na situação que por trabalhar com workers, você receberá chamadas em tempos curtos de todos os usuários que habilitar este recurso, o que pode pesar em seu servidor devido ao alto número de processos que serão abertos conforme o número de usuários do seu site/sistema aumenta.

Por exemplo:

Se seu sistema possui 100 usuários e as notificações são conferidas de 5 em 5 segundos, o mínimo de requisição que terá é 100/s e 6000/m some isso a média de número de visitas em seu site por minuto e terá o total de processos executados. Chegará a conclusão que não é uma boa deixar esse tipo de recurso na mão do PHP, pois o processamento utilizado é muito alto.

Por isso irá encontrar poucos exemplos em PHP sobre recursos como notificações.

**Algumas implementações PHP**

- https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php
- https://pusher.com/
- https://github.com/pusher-community/html5-realtime-push-notifications
- http://www.howopensource.com/2014/12/introduction-to-server-sent-events/
- https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php
- https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/

**Referências:**

- https://w3c.github.io/push-api/
- https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-useful-notifications-with-html5-apis/163
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app

Comment: Minha dúvida seria, como ter o serviço diretamente, porque devo usar sempre algo de terceiro? O que precisaria para ter meu serviço proprio?

Comment: @Roberta Atualizado. Espero que ajude.

Comment: basta usar o protocolo WebSocket corretamente. Como disse o @NewTech, PHP pode não ser a melhor ferramenta para isso. No entanto, tem um guia agnóstico interessante aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Answer (score 2):

Oi.
Tenho um código aqui. Caso não execute aqui, salve-o no seu servidor e execute diretamente.

Aí é só vc usar sua criatividade pra editar..
Dá pra manusear com Mysql

```html
 
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function notificarUsuario77(){
 // Caso window.Notification não exista, quer dizer que o browser não possui suporte a web notifications, então cancela a execução
 if(!window.Notification){
 return false;
 }
 
 // Função utilizada para enviar a notificação para o usuário
 var notificar = function(){
 var tituloMensagem = "Nova Mensagem de Sistema (Automático)!";
 var icone = "http://icon-icons.com/icons2/270/PNG/512/messages_29935.png";
 var mensagem = "Assunto: Nova resposta: crediario \n\n Vá até mensagens e verifique!";
 
 return new Notification(tituloMensagem,{
 icon : icone,
 body : mensagem
 });
 };
 
 // Verifica se existe a permissão para exibir a notificação; caso ainda não exista ("default"), então solicita permissão.
 // Existem três estados para a permissão:
 // "default" => o usuário ainda não deu nem negou permissão (neste caso deve ser feita a solicitação da permissão)
 // "denied" => permissão negada (como o usuário não deu permissão, o web notifications não irá funcionar)
 // "granted" => permissão concedida
 
 // A permissão já foi concedida, então pode enviar a notificação
 if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
 notificar();
 }else if(Notification.permission==="default"){
 // Solicita a permissão e caso o usuário conceda, envia a notificação
 Notification.requestPermission(function(permission){
 if(permission=="granted"){
 notificar();
 }
 });
 }
 };</script>


</head>

<body onload="notificarUsuario77();">
                     
 
</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo com MYSQL no meio

```html
<body onload="document.getElementById('div_abas').style.display='';
<?php 

          $buscarusuarios=mysql_query("SELECT mensagens.id as 'msg_id',
                  mensagens.data,
                  mensagens.assunto,
                  mensagens.status,

usuarios.id,
usuarios.nome

FROM mensagens
JOIN usuarios
on 
mensagens.remetente = usuarios.id
 WHERE mensagens.status='0' and  destinatario  = '".$_SESSION[id]."' ORDER by data DESC ");
                if(mysql_num_rows($buscarusuarios) == 0){
                echo"";
                }else{
                    while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($buscarusuarios)){
                      ?>notificarUsuario<?php echo $linha['msg_id'];?>();<?php }}?>">
                      <?php 

          $buscarusuarios=mysql_query("SELECT mensagens.id as 'msg_id',
                  mensagens.data,
                  mensagens.assunto,
                  mensagens.status,

usuarios.id,
usuarios.nome

FROM mensagens
JOIN usuarios
on 
mensagens.remetente = usuarios.id
 WHERE mensagens.status='0' and  destinatario  = '".$_SESSION[id]."' ORDER by data DESC limit 1");
                if(mysql_num_rows($buscarusuarios) == 0){
                echo"";
                }else{
                    while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($buscarusuarios)){
                      ?><button style="display:none;" id="notifica<?php echo $linha['msg_id'];?>" onclick="notificarUsuario<?php echo $linha['msg_id'];?>()">Testar<?php echo $linha['msg_id']?></button>
 <script>
 function notificarUsuario<?php echo $linha['msg_id'];?>(){
 // Caso window.Notification não exista, quer dizer que o browser não possui suporte a web notifications, então cancela a execução
 if(!window.Notification){
 return false;
 }
 
 // Função utilizada para enviar a notificação para o usuário
 var notificar = function(){
 var tituloMensagem = "Nova Mensagem de <?php echo utf8_encode($linha['nome']);?>!";
 var icone = "../css/imagens/nova_msg.jpg";
 var mensagem = "Assunto: <?php echo utf8_encode($linha['assunto']);?> \n\n Vá até mensagens e verifique!";
 
 return new Notification(tituloMensagem,{
 icon : icone,
 body : mensagem
 });
 };
 
 // Verifica se existe a permissão para exibir a notificação; caso ainda não exista ("default"), então solicita permissão.
 // Existem três estados para a permissão:
 // "default" => o usuário ainda não deu nem negou permissão (neste caso deve ser feita a solicitação da permissão)
 // "denied" => permissão negada (como o usuário não deu permissão, o web notifications não irá funcionar)
 // "granted" => permissão concedida
 
 // A permissão já foi concedida, então pode enviar a notificação
 if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
 notificar();
 }else if(Notification.permission==="default"){
 // Solicita a permissão e caso o usuário conceda, envia a notificação
 Notification.requestPermission(function(permission){
 if(permission=="granted"){
 notificar();
 }
 });
 }
 };</script>

 <?php }}?>
```

Comment: Olá Neto. Agradecemos sua vontade em compartilhar conhecimento, mas tenho que dizer que compartilhar apenas códigos quase sempre não é útil. O código pode até ser trivial para você, mas para outros usuários pode ser bastante confuso, então busque sempre explicar com palavras aquilo que está fazendo no código. Se o código estiver bem formatado e comentado, uma breve introdução já basta, mas busque sempre, também, citar as documentações das funções ou ferramentas utilizadas.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado. Apesar de já trabalhar na área, entrei hj no site. Mas obrigado pela dica. Vou acatar com certeza. :)