# Push em HTML5 com PHP

Tags: jquery, html5

Estou finalizando um sistema, porém gostaria de incluir as notificações push para avisar aos usuários um determinado evento. Procurei na web, mas não encontrei nada satisfatório. Acredito que eu não tenha procurado da forma correta por não conhecer muito bem essa prática. O que desejo fazer, é quando chegar um dia antes do evento, que está  armazenado em uma base de dados, apareça uma notificação ( push ) na tela do usuário. Essa notificação viria do Banco de dados com PHP. Em relação ao PHP e Banco de Dados sei fazer.

Infelizmente não tenho nenhum código referente ao Push, a única coisa que sei é que com HTML 5 dá para fazer.

A ideia seria essa. Acredito que sirva tanto para Desktop como para mobile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No post [aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203941/enviar-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-php/203943#203943), consegui o código abaixo que está funcionando:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function notificarUsuario77(){
 // Caso window.Notification não exista, quer dizer que o browser não possui suporte a web notifications, então cancela a execução
 if(!window.Notification){
 return false;
 }

 // Função utilizada para enviar a notificação para o usuário
 var notificar = function(){
 var tituloMensagem = "Nova Mensagem de Sistema (Automático)!";
 var icone = "http://icon-icons.com/icons2/270/PNG/512/messages_29935.png";
 var mensagem = "Assunto: Nova resposta: crediario \n\n Vá até mensagens e verifique!";

 return new Notification(tituloMensagem,{
 icon : icone,
 body : mensagem
 });
 };

 // Verifica se existe a permissão para exibir a notificação; caso ainda não exista ("default"), então solicita permissão.
 // Existem três estados para a permissão:
 // "default" => o usuário ainda não deu nem negou permissão (neste caso deve ser feita a solicitação da permissão)
 // "denied" => permissão negada (como o usuário não deu permissão, o web notifications não irá funcionar)
 // "granted" => permissão concedida

 // A permissão já foi concedida, então pode enviar a notificação
 if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
 notificar();
 }else if(Notification.permission==="default"){
 // Solicita a permissão e caso o usuário conceda, envia a notificação
 Notification.requestPermission(function(permission){
 if(permission=="granted"){
 notificar();
 }
 });
 }
 };</script>


</head>

<body onload="notificarUsuario77();">


</body>
</html>
```

Falta apenas integrar com o PHP.

Comment: Se e sobre programação, então claro que faz parte do escopo! Porem seria mesmo interessante algum código, ou um exemplo de algo que gostaria, mesmo que fosse com imagem

Comment: Certo Marcelo. Coloquei uma imagem do que desejo fazer. Acredito que notificações  HTML 5 funcione tanto para Desktop como para mobile.

Comment: Claro que não responde a pergunta, mas pode ter alguma ideia aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse

Comment: Certo. Vou dar uma olhada.  Encontrei esse post aqui também. O push funcionou, mas falta ver como integro o PHP no código. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203941/enviar-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-php/203943#203943